# Request email and password Facebook from your app?

Tags: ios

I am making app logging with Facebook. I request to take Facebook account information (facebook_ID, gender, birthday) so how to take password and email Facebook app???

Answer (score 0):

you wont get the password  from facebook , read about oauth specifics , email you can still get  from facebook I think it is extended permission request . If you are using iOS 6 and above recommended to use the [socaiframework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233)

Answer (score 0):

Use permission for access token as `@"user_birthday" in for o-auth ,i.e use api_key , re-direct url` .

And then make a request to `"@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=_access-token_""`.

This for external usage .That means calling facebook api .

From `iOS 6` . `Facebook SDK` is available  . Try with that

Comment: You can talk more detail? I predict your idea and I do this:  NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]]; the JSON call back can search the username and pass with what key???